# iPhone Web App Div Tag Reloading in Safari

Tags: css, html, javascript, iphone

My iOS Web app is written in HTML and CSS. I have a text link that shows/hides a div layer. It works flawlessly but when I change the visibility of the div tag it reloads the page in safari, rther than displying the div in the webapp . Here is my code to enable the Webapp interface:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Here is my javascript to display the div tag when a link is clicked:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
 <!--
 var state = 'none';

 function showhide(layer_ref) {

 if (state == 'block') { 
 state = 'none'; 
 } 
 else { 
 state = 'block'; 
 } 
 if (document.getElementById &&!document.all) { 
 hza = document.getElementById(layer_ref); 
 hza.style.display = state; 
 } 
 } 
 //--> 
 </script>
```

The div layer:
    
    content

And Lastly, the link that shows the div:

```
<a href="#" class="Action" onclick="showhide('optionpanel');">Menu</a>
```

Comment: This seems to be primarily programming related. That's StackOverflow's territory.

Answer (score 1):

I think `display = 'block'` is defined to show the div and force a reload at the same time. So what you're seeing is how it's meant to work.

To make a div visible without the reload/update you need set the visibility flag instead. Use:

```
hza.style.visibility = state;
```

Where state is either 'visible' or 'hidden'.

Comment: Setting visibility but not display causes a huge gap in the document where the missing `<div>` would go

Comment: also, this doesn't actually make a difference - my browser is still jumping up to the top of the page (not reloading, though)

Answer (score 0):

Does adding `return false;` to the end of `showhide` help?